# Salesfoce REST API GET all opportunities by all owners

Tags: rest-api, api, opportunity, rest

I have the following API request which returns opportunities.

...services/data/v54.0/query?q=SELECT FIELDS(ALL) FROM Opportunity LIMIT 20

My problem is that this call only seems to return opportunities with the ownerid of the
API account, but I need to return all opportunities regardless of the opportunity owner.
All I'm provided with is the limited API account, does this have to do with my user permission or is it a limitation of the API request?

Thank you.

Comment: The broader data security set up in the org is the answer. You might be calling it "user permission". See https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_overview for an overview

Comment: Most likely this is because of sharing restrictions on your API user (Org Wide Defaults, Declarative or Apex Sharing, etc.). This access would have to be modified by a System Administrator

Comment: @identigral Understood. Thank you.